# Fluentd file output does not output to file

Tags: fluentd

On Ubuntu 18.04, I am running td-agent v4 which uses Fluentd v1.0 core.  First I configured it with TCP input and stdout output.  It receives and outputs the messages fine.  I then configure it to output to file with a 10s flush interval, yet I do not see any output files generated in the destination path.

This is my file output configuration:

```
<match>
  @type file
  path /var/log/td-agent/test/access.%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S.log
  <buffer time>
    timekey 10s
    timekey_use_utc true
    timekey_wait 2s
    flush_interval 10s
  </buffer>
</match>
```

I perform this check every 10s to see if log files are generated, but all I see is a directory with a name that still has the placeholders that I set for the `path` param:

```
ls -la /var/log/td-agent/test
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 td-agent td-agent 4096 Feb  5 23:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 td-agent td-agent 4096 Feb  6 00:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 td-agent td-agent 4096 Feb  5 23:14 access.%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S.log
```

From following the Fluentd docs, I was expecting this should be fairly straight forward since the file output and buffering plugins are bundled with Fluentd's core.

Am I missing something trivial here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and it works now.  I had two outputs, one to file and another to stdout.  Apparently that won't work if they're both defined separately in the config file with their own `<match> ... </match>`.  I believe output to stdout was read first in the config, so Fluentd outputted to that and not to file.  They should both instead be nested under the `copy` output like this:

```
<match>
  @type copy

  <store>
    @type file
    ...
  </store>

  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```